# Ngx-auth without refresh-token

Tags: angular, authentication, authorization, jwt, access-token

I have a task to make authentication. They want to use ngx-auth - firstly, they wanted to implement as the documentation says 2 tokens: access and refresh. But now they want to do it only with 1 token. My question is:
1) Is it worth and possible to use that package without refresh token? I think that package mostly bases on that refresh token.
2) How to check the expiration of token? Is it by `exp` parameter as in basic jwt? How often should I check token validity - on every request or should I e.g. every 15min?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library.  To ignore RefreshToken just override proper method to do nothing.

To check validity decode token (base64) and check `exp` attribute to know if is expired or not. You should do this before every request via `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR`. If token expired then request for new one and replay original query.

The bigger problem is **how to regenerate expired token if you do not want to use expiration tokens?** You can not store username and password on the client side. Backend needs to provide some endpoint that allow regenerate token by passing expired one.

Token should not be valid for long time. If your clients do not want refresh tokens and maybe? wants to make tokens valid for eg. 24h then consider to put client IP address inside token and validate it at every incoming request. This is not common approach but good for "hard" clients who do not follow standards (like additional security mechanism).

@Edit

I checked *ngx-auth* source code and approach of refreshing token is little bit different. Author if this library refresh token when backend return `401 Unauthorized` to the client. In this case you do not have to validate `exp` attribute. Just intercept all incoming responses and if status is 401 it means we have to refresh our token.

Token service in this library is just abstract interface without logic. **You have to extend AuthService class** and provide your own implementation for particular methods.

Please check **ngx-auth-example** repository https://github.com/serhiisol/ngx-auth-example/blob/master/src/app/shared/authentication/authentication.service.ts

Here you have simple implementation of this library.

You don't want to use refresh tokens. In this case override `refreshToken` method and find any other way to handle re-authorization.

Comment: So the library doesn't provide usecase to handle expiration token? I don't want to check expiration time on my own if library provide that and ngx-auth must provide that so I want to know how can I do this without refresh token.

Comment: Library doesn't support decoding token to check `exp` attribute. Instead of this library refreshing token when backend return 401. I updated my post.